# Load image not in xap Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, image, load

i'm developing an application and i would load an image that isn't in the clientbin folder, but in a folder placed in my server. I would do something like this 
            BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage();
            string path = "c:/image.png";
            bit.UriSource = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
            identity.Source = bit;
but it doesn't function.Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Image.Source = New Imaging.BitmapImage(New Uri("http://www.Pic.jpg", UriKind.Absolute))

You do not want to include it in your project or the .xap will get huge.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight applications run on the client, not on the server, so referencing the path as you had been trying to do, would really point to the path on client machine running the application. However, Silverlight does not have rights to read or write from or to the client's disk anyway, due to sercurity reasons. The Isolated Storage functionality is the exception to that.

Therefore, your option is to try the first answer given by Bill, or a WebService, which is more complex to implement.

ib.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Bill's answer.  You can also use server side resources using the following helper method which is derived from the location of the xap file.

```
public static string GetUrlForResource(string resourcePage)
{

    var webUrl = Application.Current.Host.Source.ToString();
    //Get ClientBin Directory
    var stub = webUrl.Substring(0, webUrl.LastIndexOf("/"));
    //Get application root.
    stub = stub.Substring(0, stub.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    //Append the application root to the resource page.
    webUrl = stub + resourcePage;

    return webUrl;
}
```

To use it like Bill's answer, use the following:

```
Image.Source = new Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(GetUrlForResource("images/myimage.png"), UriKind.Absolute));
```